# Removing Yet not Deleting an Element/Variable from an HTML Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, menu

I am testing out with a different way of menus. My code is the following:

**JavaScript**

```
var hubOpen = 0;
var test = "test";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#hub').click(function(){
            if(hubOpen == 0){
                $('#hub').append(test);
                hubOpen = 1;
            } else {
                //code for taking "test" out here
                hubOpen = 0;
            };
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <p id="hub">Hub</p>
</body>
```

If you'd like, here's a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bn5Vf/3/). The code is to make sure that when the id "hub" is clicked, "test" appears. When hub is clicked again, "test" disappears. The code, when run, opens test, doesn't let you click it again, but it doesn't delete "test" (as there is no code for it).

My question: How would I delete the variable "test" from the document but not to delete the variable forever, as I would need to use it later? Would the jQuery method

```
.replace();
```

work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself – don't just link to it.

Comment: How would you need that variable later? What are you going to do with it lateR?

Comment: @Jack, Please refer to the comments of the below answer. This was not the full thing. I am just doing this to have a proof-of-concept for making a toggle-able button that shows another element/variable. Hope that cleared things up.

Comment: @Matt, thanks for the information. I will take it into account in the future.

Comment: Okay, then why not just use `.toggle()`?

Comment: @Jack: Thank you, but please next time refer to existing answers. Also, if I knew about .toggle() I wouldn't be asking, am I right?

Comment: I'm not a search engine; my comment is meant to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all the contents of an element, jQuery offers `.empty()`:

```
$('#hub').empty();
```

The variable is completely separate from the element, so no problems there. If you wanted to restore the original text, just use `.text()`:

```
$('#hub').text('Hub');
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/bn5Vf/4/)

Comment: As I said, I need to use #hub and test again, so permanently emptying it will not suffice. Thanks, though.

Comment: @JustinChang: You have a variable. It’s still there. If a variable doesn’t work for your needs for some reason, could you please add more detail as to what this is for?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was using the document for a "proof-of-concept" of, as I said in the question, a new way to make a drop-down "toolbar".

Comment: @JustinChang: Stick it in a `<div>` and call `show()`/`hide()`/`toggle()` on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hub').click(function(){
         $(this).text() == 'Hub' ? $(this).html('text') : $(this).html('Hub');
    });
});
```

On click if the text is 'Hub' change it to 'text' else change it again to 'Hub'.